# Setting width to Html.BeginForm() in MVC 3

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a MVC view having following code.

```
<table width="960" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
</table>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
            {

        <table width="960" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <tr>
                <td>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .
}
                </td>
             </tr>
        </table>
```

As you can see both tables above and be `@using (Html.BeginForm())` having width as 960, but as this code renders in browser it automatically giving width as 1100px to `form tag` (`Html.BeginForm()` in code). I have no idea where its coming from? I am thinking of setting width in `Html.BeginForm()` or is there better idea but I don't even know how to set width to `Html.BeginForm()`. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good idea will be to give width in css file

```
table form{
width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do what vaibhav shah suggests, you need to add a reference to the css class in the form post. Like this:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "DocCodes", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal"}))
            { code.. }
```